# Can a UIView be auto-repositioned based on surrounding views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with multiple subviews representing rows (similar to a UITableView). I want to insert a new view underneath one of my rows. If I were using a UITableView I would simply use `tableview:insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to insert a row at a particular index. What is the best way to replicate this behavior? My only thought at the moment is to iterate through all the subviews beneath my new view and push each frame down by Y (height of view I am inserting). Is there any way to make my subviews self aware of their surroundings (much like inserting a DIV in HTML) so I do not have to explicitly specify the frame of each view?

[image: Insert a view]

Comment: are you using Auto Layout?

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to automatically do this, but you could use ```insertSubview:atIndex:``` and then iterate through the subviews of the parent view and adjust frames in your parent view's ```layoutSubviews``` method.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I am using Auto Layout, but I haven't created constraints programmatically. Will try out your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice here is to make your life easier and use a `UICollectionView` with a flow layout.
It's very flexible and it allows you to easily manage insert/deletion of items.

Another approach with you custom `UIScrollView` would be to use Auto Layout to specify the relative constraints between the newly inserted view and the surrounding ones. Animating the layout change will likely give you the desired effect.

Comment: +1 for UICollectionView.  Also, if it really is just a vertically scrolling list of items, why not just go for UITableView?  They are quite flexible.

Comment: Right. I implicitly assumed that `UITableView` doesn't fit the OP need, anyway we should hear from him why he decided no to use it in the first place.

Comment: Honestly I'm most comfortable using a `UITableView` but I encountered an issue that I don't feel is solvable without moderate hacks. If the `UICollectionView` doesn't work out then I'll likely create a new post regarding my `UITableView` issue. My view will only have between 1 and 20 rows, so I do not feel that I need the memory optimizations that a `UITableView` provides.

Comment: Even though you may not benefit from the memory optimizations, `UITableView` still provides many other convenient behaviors, such as insertion/deletion. I'd stick with that, or with `UICollectionView`, which is de facto an abstraction of `UITableView`.

Comment: `UICollectionView` seems like the way to go based on my reading so I am accepting this as the answer. I ended up using my `UIScrollView` because I already had most of the code for it. I track each view/row that I add to my scroll view and adjust frames as needed.